# How to do 'mvn compile' and 'mvn package' with m2e in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I've started this week to use Maven for some projects I'm working on and I use Eclipse with the m2e plugin. I've been having a look at it but I can't find a way to compile and package (as far as I can see I can do clean, generate-sources, test and install). How can this be achieved with m2e?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Right click on your project
2. Run As
3. Maven build...
4. Fill in the goals you want
5. Hit Run

Comment: Where is the documentation that would have allowed me to figure this out for myself? I can't find anything useful at http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

Answer (score 1):

You have to create own Run Configuration of type Maven Build. These four are some kind of predefined builds, but you can create really customized own stuff.