# noClassDefFound error with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to create a spigot/bukkit plugin that monitors information about player connections, I've been trying to add [MaxMind's GeoIP2 java api](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-java/) and the last time I asked [how to add it's dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33261523/how-to-add-dependencies-for-maxmind-geoip2-eclipse). I've installed M2e and added the dependency for geoip2 but when I run my bukkit test server I get this error:

> [20:35:14] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling ConnectionInfo v0.0.1.15 (Is it up to date?)
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/maxmind/geoip2/exception/GeoIp2Exception
>       at net.comdude2.plugins.connectioninfo.main.ConnectionInfo.onEnable(ConnectionInfo.java:107) ~[?:?]
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:335) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
>       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:356) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
>       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:316) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
>       at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.q(MinecraftServer.java:402) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
>       at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.k(MinecraftServer.java:370) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
>       at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:325) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
>       at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:211) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
>       at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:505) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_65]
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.maxmind.geoip2.exception.GeoIp2Exception
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:101) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
>       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:86) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-c3c767f-33d5de3]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
>       ... 12 more
>   [20:35:14] [Server thread/INFO]: Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty, ignoring it

My code and pom.xml can be [found here](https://github.com/comdude2/ConnectionInfo).

I just need to know how to add the dependency if I'm doing it wrong, I'm not new to java but I am new to Maven and Dependencies so please be patient with me, any help is appreciated.

P.S. I'm not trying to locate IP "0.0.0.0", I have pushed it as that to protect my own IP address.

Comment: Maven downloads appropriate libraries into its repository (~/.m2 by default) but you have to make sure that library .jar files are added to the classpath when running your program.

Comment: My classpath: http://pastebin.com/7TDz1SqV Is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my own problem, It was because I needed to run my project as a Maven build.

If you're having the same problem [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313171/how-to-do-mvn-compile-and-mvn-package-with-m2e-in-eclipse) helped me.

I used the package goal as that's what I needed.

I also needed to change my pom to enable it to export dependencies into the built jar.